# Output window changes "Debug" to "Source control - Git"

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I am using the output window to output some debug info.

For some reason, Visual Studio occasionally changes the dropdown labeled "Show output from:" from "Debug" to "Source control - Git".

Why?

Can I stop this?

Comment: Does it change while you are debugging?

Comment: It changes the next day, sometimes. Never when I look at it.

Comment: To me it seems that that Source control - Git is the default choice for the output window when I open Visual Studio. My Visual Studio changes the choice to Debug for the output window when I start debugging. I have not thought that much more about it.

Comment: It also switches while building... sometimes...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this (and the comment on 6/30/2020), it's a known bug and a fix is being prepared for release: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/411653/output-show-output-from-selects-source-control-git.html

Will they fix all aspects of the bug? Let's hope so.